# How can I keep grunt separate from my source files?

Tags: bash, gruntjs

I've spent about a day trying to figure this out.

What I finally did was a bash script:

```
gw() {
  # runs grunt using this path 
  cd ~/root_install/grunt
  grunt watch &
  cd ~/root
}
```

My install file are in `root_install` and my source file are in `root`.

Note installing the grunt task runner globally is deprecated.

Note that setting the location of the Gruntfile.js does not work as it appears to need a local installation of the task runner.

This seems to be the deal killer.

But alas, application files I want separate from my source files and Grunt is an application.

What I have works, but it is a bit hackish as I don't want to spend any more time on this.